# Array in Object returns undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, object

I want to loop through an array in a object, but it seems it returns undefined.

Why does it return undefined? I see the array contains items.

[image: Debugger]

[image: Object]

Thanks!

Comment: Please produce a minimal code (in text format, not an image), that reproduces the problem, so we can test it ourselves.

Comment: It is difficult to tell with this code. But, in Angular when you get undefined in one place and it seems like there is an object in another, the problem is typically because of the asynchronous nature of JavaScript and especially AngularJS. So, when the code runs the array isn't populated yet, but then it does get populated after you try to parse it. Give us some more code and we can get a better idea.

Comment: Thats true, I will provide a small piece of code in a fiddle :). Thanks :)

Comment: I got here a small demo @trincot http://inquota-dev.nl/angular/

Comment: I looked at the demo. I saw a 350 line JS file. No clue what you are pointing at. This can hardly be called a minimal code to show a problem.

Answer (score -2):

from what i can see, you are referencing "children" before declaration.

```
var children = $rootScope.Angular.nodes[0].children
       ^                                      ^
```

I'm not sure due to the small writing, but this may be the problem

Comment: `var children` is a local variable declaration and `nodes[0].children` is accessing a property named children from the first node. So, it's not referencing children before it's declared.

Comment: I tried to put the `var children = $rootScope.Angular.nodes[0].children` after the fetchChildren method, it didnt work.